# MaterialDateTimePicker MinDate , MaxDate issue

Tags: android, datepicker, material-design

MaterialDateTimePicker library used as DateTime picker in Android application. Required to disable previous and future dates to show only 3 days in the calendar ie. yesterday, today and tomorrow. Everything works fine except the date picked is 1 month back . for example while selecting today ( 16-05-2017) it fetches one month prior date ( 15-04-2017) . 
Its showing 1 month back date instead of 1 day back .
Code :

```
calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        Year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) ;
        Month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        Day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        final Calendar maxDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        maxDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, maxDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + 1);
        maxDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, Month);
        maxDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, Year);

        final Calendar minDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        minDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Day - 1);
        minDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, Month);
        minDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, Year);


        mDojBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(TrainStatus.this, Year, Month, Day);
                datePickerDialog.setThemeDark(false);
                datePickerDialog.showYearPickerFirst(false);
                datePickerDialog.setAccentColor(Color.parseColor("#009688"));
                datePickerDialog.setTitle("Select Date");
                datePickerDialog.setMinDate(minDate);
                datePickerDialog.setMaxDate(maxDate);

                datePickerDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "DatePickerDialog");

            }
        });

@Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePickerDialog view, int Year, int Month, int Day) {
        dateSelected = String.valueOf(Year)+String.valueOf(Month)+String.valueOf(Day);

    }
```

Any help is appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 You should add month +1. because here month starts from zero(0).

dateSelected = String.valueOf(Year)+String.valueOf(Month +1)+String.valueOf(Day);


Or

   final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            dialog = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePickerDialog view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    month = monthOfYear;
                    day = dayOfMonth;
                    TextView tv = (TextView) v1.findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
                    tv.setText(new StringBuilder().append(day).append("-")
                            .append((month + 1)).append("-").append(year));
                }
            }, yy, mm, dd);

            dialog.setMinDate(calendar);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer , that was really silly mistake from me.

Answer (score 0):

```
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html
```

check the official doc for calendar class, month start with 0. that means 0= january , and 11=december.